# how do i restart an if statement

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

im sorry if the title is not specific but i need some help:
im trying to do a little guessing game and i am trying to implement a hint

```
  #!/bin/bash
echo "what comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?
(lowercase)"
read input
if [ $input = "m" ] ; then
clear
echo "correct"
sleep 4.4
clear
elif [ $input = "hint" ] ; then
clear
echo "its a letter"   #what do i do so that after it prints "its a letter"
clear                 #it comes back to the beginning of the if statement 
else
clear
echo "incorrect"
sleep 4.4
clear
fi
```

for example: i run the script

-it will print `what comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?`
-i reply `hint` and after it gives the hint it comes back to waiting for me to input the answer

Comment: Please learn to indent your code.

Comment: Use an endless while loop

Comment: @Guack : You also should remove the spaces before the `#!` in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a function with recursion

```
game () {
    read -p "what comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?
    (lowercase) " input # make read print it

    # use case instead of if\then
    case $input in
     "hint") clear; echo "its a letter"; game;;
        "m") clear; echo "correct"; sleep 4.4; game;;
          *) clear; echo "incorrect"; sleep 4.4; game;;
    esac 
}

game
```

Comment: Remove the call to `game` after the good answer. I shouldn't use `clear`.

Comment: Avoid recursion when a while loop is possible too (and easier).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have more questions/answers quized, and want to do something like

```
quiz() {
   if [[ $# -ne 3 ]]; then
      echo 'Call this function like quiz "question" "hint" "answer"'
      echo "All arguments in single or double quotes."
   fi
   # Now implement something with `while` and use `break` after a good answer of give-up
   # ... your code ;-)
}

# Advanced: Store questions/hints/answers in an array and use a while loop 

set1_q='what comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?'
set1_h='its a letter'
set1_a='m'
# set1_e for an explanation?
set2_q='Solve x in (x-a).(x-b).(x-c). ... (x-z) = x'
set2_h='Did you notice (x-x)?'
set2_a='0'

quiz "${set1_q}" "${set1_h}" "${set1_a}"
quiz "${set2_q}" "${set2_h}" "${set2_a}"
```

Comment: just a question what does -ne mean?

Comment: `-ne` means `Not Equals`. Comparing integers is done different than strings. When you use single hooks like `[ some_test ]` (`[` is an alternative name of `test`, see `man test`), you must use something soecial for tests like `less than` (`-lt`) or `greater equals` (`-gt`). In bash you have the (better!) alternative `if (( $# !=3 )); then`.